# Prevent GCC warning "value computed is not used" for a macro

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I'm working on a macro that will support error handling.

```
#define Try(e, call)   ( (e == OK) && ((e = call) != OK) )
```

It can be used as the expression of an if-statement:

```
if (Try(err, SomeFunction(foo, bar))) {
    // Entered only if err was OK before the if-statement and SomeFunction()
    // returned a non-OK value.
}
```

The function won't be called if `err` was already non-OK before the if-statement. After the if-statement `err` will be set to the return value of `SomeFunction()`.

So far so good. However I also want to use the macro without an if-statement:

```
Try(err, SomeFunction(foo, bar));
```

In this case GCC gives the following warning:

```
warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
```

And that's what my question is about: how can I rewrite the macro such that GCC won't produce this warning. I know the warning can be disabled with a flag (but I want to keep it enabled for other code) or by casting the result explicitly to `void`. The following statement code won't produce the warning:

```
(void) Try(err, SomeFunction(foo, bar));
```

But it's far from ideal to prefix each `Try()` with a `void` cast. Any suggestions?

Comment: Two macros, `Check(e,call)` what now is `Try`, and `#define Try(e,call) (void)Check(e,call)`?

Comment: @DanielFischer: That's indeed what I have in mind if I cannot find another solution, but I would prefer to solve this with a single macro.

Comment: No dice, I'm afraid. You need to return a value for the use in the `if`, and any naked call would then be an unused value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator like this:

```
( (e == OK) ? ((e = call) != OK) : (e == OK) )
```

Comment: Why not 0? [Works for me.](http://www.mirbsd.org/cvs.cgi/src/bin/mksh/sh.h.diff?r1=1.923;r2=1.924) (Also, thanks for the recommendation of how to reword this to silence the stupid compiler; I linked this answer from the commit message.)

Comment: @mirabilos I can't remember why I wrote that, so I removed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for something like this

```
inline
bool notOK(int err) {
  return err != OK;
}

#define Try(e, call)   ( !notOK(e) && notOK(e = call) )
```

Usually compilers don't complain about function return values that are not used.

For debugging purposes it might be necessary also to add an "instantiation"

```
bool notOK(int err);
```

in a .c file.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea.

```
static inline int identity (int x) { return x; }
#define Try(e, call)   (identity ((e == OK) && ((e = call) != OK)))
```

You may want to `#define inline __inline__` or `#define inline /*nothing*/` for non-gcc compilers.

Comment: Any C99-compliant compiler accepts the `inline` keyword, although that leaves many compilers that do not accept it. (“non-gcc” makes it sound like an extension, which it no longer is, is all).